# How to solve, file not found error from script, but works in notebook?

Tags: python, json, filenotfoundexception

I have a code to load a json file.

```
with open("data/movie_data.json", "r") as j:
    word_map = json.load(j)
```

The data folder is in current directory. However, this code works in the jupyter notebook, but while running from a script, it says, file not found error. Both the script and notebook are in same folder, that contains 'data' folder. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running the script directly? Also, what is the working directory of your shell (are you running it in the correct folder?)?

Comment: My script and notebook are in "MyFolder", data is in "MyFolder/data." Now, I check the working directory from script, os.listdir("."). That shows, the scrip current directory is "TwoLevelsUpDirectory". Making me puzzled. I solved the issue, adding the full path. Still needs some explanation, if someone has one!

Comment: What do you use to run the script? PyCharm? Spyder? Command line?

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` -- your IDE runs your program from whatever directory it feels like. this isn't like lexical scoping.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"./data/movie_data.json"
```

instead of

```
"data/movie_data.json"
```

Comment: Those are equivalent

Comment: This also didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.